# Delete an application data having same linux userid and signed with same key as my application

Tags: android

In android i want to delete the data of other application, actually the other application is also of mine so is it possible to delete the other application data by sharing the userId and signed with the same keystore.

If possible with some other tricks please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Does the applications share the same package? If not, then I don't think it possible. Have you tried uninstalling the previous application?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg as per my knowledge two apps cant have the same package name here I am talking about two different applications.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why it would work, if the Android phone would consider the applications as being "the same app". Of course, then you wouldn't be able to start the different apps on the phone. I don't think what you are trying to do is possible, but I can't say that I am certain of it.